# Facebook redirect loop when running locally

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I'm working on a local Facebook project. But when I go to localhost, he starts redirecting to **localhost/?code=xxxx** everytime (xxxx is very long random characters).

My code is:

```
require_once('sdk/src/facebook.php');

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'MY_APP_ID',
  'secret' => 'MY_APP_SECRET',
  'sharedSession' => true,
  'trustForwarded' => true,
  'cookie' => true
));

$user_id = $facebook->getUser();
if ($user_id) {
  try {
    // Fetch the viewer's basic information
    $basic = $facebook->api('/me','GET');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    if (!$facebook->getUser()) {
      //header('Location: '. AppInfo::getUrl($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));
      $user_id = null;
    }
  }
}

if(!$user_id) {
    $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
    'scope' => 'email,publish_actions'
  ));
    
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>top.location.href = '$loginUrl';</script>";
      exit();
}
...
```

My app settings:
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That might indicate that your session is lost – check if your browser accepts PHP’s session cookies for your localhost correctly.

Comment: @CBroe My Chrome browser doesn't accept cookies, but Firefox do. And unfortunately, redirect loop is happening on all my browsers. What can I do?

Comment: Also try removing `sharedSession` and `trustForwarded` parameters when initializing the SDK, if you don’t really need them.

Answer (score 1):

The likely issue is that your app is returning `0` for `$user_id` even after the user has logged in, causing the JavaScript redirect to happen again, causing it to loop forever.

The case of the issue may be one of many things, but make sure the `code` GET variable isn't being stripped out of the URL by a `.htaccess` file or other means. Secondly, take a look at [this modification](https://www.webniraj.com/2012/12/19/facebook-php-sdk-fixing-getuser-on-php-5-4-x/) to the `base_facebook.php` file to change the way the `code` is checked.